# trying to make a new texture painting so i can create a specular map, but old texture painting won't go away

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-painting

[image]

as you can see, i have a pitch black texture painting named glossymap both in the materials tab and up on my texture editor, but the actual mesh isn't changing. it does change in layout mode, but i CANNOT draw on it, when i try, it only applies to the old texture painting and when i pull it back up, marks i made when it was deleted are on it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdewkg3thnrw608/skinpractice.blend?dl=0 blend file should be here, new to dropbox so idk if it allows others to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Active Tool and Workspace Properties* (the icon with the wrench and screwdriver on the right) you need to select the image (and UV map) on which you want to paint on.

Alternatively, you can select *Mode* = `Material` and connect the *Image Texture* node to the output in the *Shader Editor*, just for the time you are painting. (With a *UV Map* node you can select there the UV map. You have only a single UV map but just saying.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank you so much, blunder <3